# Is there a way to perform column-wise convolution in MATLAB using conv()?

Tags: matlab, matrix, convolution

I have two 2D matrices with the **same number of columns**, `A` and `B`. I want to convolve the corresponding columns of these two matrices and store the result into a new one call it `result`.  Assuming that `result` has the appropriate dimensions, my current approach is something like:

```
for i = 1 : size( A, 2 ) % number of columns
    result(:,i) = conv( A(:,i), B(:,i) );
end
```

Is there a way to avoid this loop using `conv()` or perhaps `conv2()` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the relationship between (circular) convolution and DFT, and exploit the fact that [`fft`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html), unlike [`conv2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html), can work along a specified dimension:

```
A = rand(5,7);
B = rand(4,7); % example matrices. Same number of columns
s = size(A,1)+size(B,1)-1; % number of rows of result
result = ifft(fft(A,s,1).*fft(B,s,1));
```

Note that due to floating-point numerical precision there may be slight differences, of the order of [`eps`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html), between this result and that obtained with `for` and `conv`. In particular, if your inputs are real the result may have a (very small) imaginary part, so you may want to apply [`real`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/real.html) to the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `conv` function you can try `conv(A_i,B_i, 'full')` but
you can also use below code for convolution, e.g. for column convolution `convIt(A,B,1)` and for row convolution  `convIt(A,B,2)`

```
function C = convIt(A,B,dim)
% the code is equivalent to running conv(A_i,B_i, 'full') in matlab
% (where A_i and B_i are columns (dim=1) or rows (dim=2) of A,B)
% and then stack the results together

if 1==dim || nargin<3 % default
  A = [A;zeros(size(A))];
  B = [B;zeros(size(B))];
elseif 2==dim
  A = [A,zeros(size(A))];
  B = [B,zeros(size(B))];
end
C = ifft(fft(A,[],dim).*fft(B,[],dim),[],dim);
if 1==dim || nargin<3 % default
  C = C(1:end-1,:);
elseif 2==dim
  C = C(:,1:end-1);
end
```